# android sqlite update row with like

Tags: android, sql, t-sql, sql-update

I'm working sqlite.i wrote one function witch must update row with some values
this is a my source

```
public void updateLoanId (long id, String productId){

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("LoanAnalisysID", id);

    db.update(LoanAnalysisGraph_Table, values, "ViewId like " + productId + "%", null);
}
```

i try to update LoanAnalysisGraph_Table  table  by  ViewId.when i run program i have syntax error near %
i don't know what is a wrong in my syntax
if anyone knows solution please help me .thanks

Comment: I think it should be `"ViewId like '" + productId + "%'"` @abduloiche

Answer (score 0):

We have to enclose the productId in between single quotation. So change your update method like below

```
db.update(LoanAnalysisGraph_Table, values, "ViewId like '" + productId + "%'", null);
```

Comment: thanks.when i call my function in productID I inserted for example 200 and i want to update all LoanAnalisysID where ViewId starting 200..and my code not working perfect...